# Multiples consultas en mysql para un sistema de nomina

Tags: mysql, sql

necesito una gran ayuda,  tengo la siguiente estructura en la bd:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Explico mas o menos la lógica que utilizo:

1- la tabla integrales_has_catalogo la utilizo para agrupar algunos códigos del catalogo, los que me sean mas comunes ejemplo: bajo el  codigo_integral 1001 están El sueldo básico y seguro social de mi tabla Catalogo.

2- la tabla Pagos_Estandar ahí guardo la cantidad de dinero que voy a pagar de algún concepto de la nomina  según el cargo, ejemplo: El sueldo básico del cargo Gerente es 20 $ o si quiero colocar alguna bonificación según el cargo

necesito generar el siguiente reporte sin importar que algunos campos sean nulos motivo por el cual, que algunos conceptos de nomina no le coloco un monto especifico, basicamente necesito que al decir que me de los conceeptos de nomina que estan bajo el codigo de la integral 1001 ejemplo , se los asigne al empleado y verifique si no estandarice alguno de los conceptos , casi siempre seran los sueldos o x concepto adicional que agregue mas adelante, aqui anexo la imagen del reporte como deberia verse  :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

de antemano agradecido con el que pueda resolver esto, quizas sea sencillo pero de verdad lo he intentado varias veces y no lo genera tal cual.

este es el sql que llevo hasta el momento:

select * from (SELECT t.*,d.idDepartamento,d.Nombre as Departamento,c.IdCargo,
c.Nombre as Cargo FROM trabajador t inner join cargo c on c.IdCargo=t.cargo_IdCargo
inner join departamento d on d.idDepartamento=c.Departamento_idDepartamento
where t.Tipo_Contrato='FIJO' and Status='Activo') t1 inner join pagos_estandar p on p.cargo_IdCargo=t1.IdCargo
right outer join (select * from integrales_has_catalogo i
inner join catalogo c on c.Codigo=i.catalogo_Codigo ) t2 on t2.catalogo_Codigo=p.Cod_Catalg
where t2.Integrales_Codigo='1001' order by t1.Cedula asc, t2.Codigo asc;

y asi es el resultado hasta el momento

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esta es mi bd  aqui dejo el enlace:

[bd nomina](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-VH7rchOP4TLeZR490C1qf28__Q9U54c/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta incluyendo qué has intentado y el dataset (phpmyadmin->Exportar) con unos datos de muestra para tratar de obtener el resultado que esperas

Comment: listo pregunta actualizada, agregue lo que me pediste

Comment: No termino de entender tu modelo, por qué `detalle_nomina` está vacía, y por qué no hay relación entre las tablas que describes

Comment: bueno detalle_nomina ahí guardare lo que calcule de cada concepto de nomina, ese seria el paso siguiente, no influye mucho, igualmente hace un rato encontré la solución , de igual modo la subiré, y disculpa si no me supe explicar jajaj gracias

Answer (score 1):

de tanto intentos finalmente logre resolver lo que necesitaba, anexo el código:

```
 select
  t1.*,
  t2.*,
  IFNULL(t3.Monto,0) as Monto,
  IFNULL(t3.Moneda,'-') as Moneda
from (SELECT
    t.*,
    d.idDepartamento,
    d.Nombre as Departamento,
    c.IdCargo,
    c.Nombre as Cargo
FROM
    trabajador t
    inner join cargo c on c.IdCargo=t.cargo_IdCargo
    inner join departamento d on d.idDepartamento=c.Departamento_idDepartamento
    where t.Tipo_Contrato='FIJO' and Status='Activo') t1
CROSS JOIN
  (select * from integrales_has_catalogo i
  inner join catalogo c on c.Codigo=i.catalogo_Codigo where i.Integrales_Codigo='1001') t2
LEFT JOIN
  (select
  d.idDepartamento,
  d.Nombre as Departamento,
  ca.IdCargo,
  ca.Nombre as Cargo,
  p.Cod_Catalg,
  p.Monto,
  p.Moneda
from pagos_estandar p
  inner join cargo ca on ca.IdCargo=p.cargo_IdCargo
  inner join departamento d  on d.idDepartamento=ca.Departamento_idDepartamento) t3
on t3.IdCargo=t1.IdCargo and t3.Cod_Catalg=t2.catalogo_Codigo
order by t1.Cedula asc,t2.Codigo;
```

Con el CROSS JOIN era el fragmento de código que necesitaba , ya que al consultar mis empleados según sea la condición que le coloque,  el cross join unirá de la tabla integrales_has_catalogo todos los conceptos de nomina que estén bajo la integral 1001 y verificara si hay un monto pre-establecido de algún concepto de mi tabla pago_Estandar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]